Is there a way to update a PKPASS on Google Wallet in the same way that a PKPASS is updated using APNs on iOS?
On iOS, a PKPASS on Apple Wallet can be updated using a web service and APNs without the user having to redownload the PKPASS to see updated information. Is there a way to do this with a PKPASS added to Google Wallet?
I've been able to update the PKPASS by downloading a new version from the same source as the original PKPASS, but I've seen little to no information in being able to do the same functionality as APNs and Apple Wallet with Google Wallet.
